# Assembly Language Coprocessor

Tags: c, assembly, trigonometry, processor

Imagine you have a computer, Computer B, that only has a tangent function and can only return accurate results on the tangent of an angle between 0 and 45 degrees.   Given an angle, ø, greater than 45 degrees and less than 90, what mathematical operations could be performed to return an accurate tangent value? Also provide a detailed example.

I need some help on this. This tan problem is in terms of the coprocessor and FPTAN instruction. Any ideas?

Comment: out of the 20 questions I had to hw, I only posted one that I truly having problems with. sorry for that

Comment: People are willing to offer help, but tend to get a bit antsy if you don't tag a homework question as such. The double angle formulae might be relevant? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html

Comment: @Nos I am quite sure I should do not do his homework for him.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like homework, so as a hint: given a right angle triangle, if one angle is greater than 45 deg, then the other is less than 45 deg.  Furthermore

```
    cos(PHI) = sin(THETA)
    sin(PHI) = cos(THETA)
```

If `PHI` and `THETA` are the angles in your triangle.  I believe that should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that `1/TAN(θ)=COT(θ)=TAN(π/2-θ)`.